# Return next 5 rows using LINQ in C# ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm using LINQ to query my database, and I don't want all the records returned all at once. Instead, user should be able to select *Next 5* and *Previous 5* using buttons. As of this moment I have selected the first 5 rows in the Item table in the databas like this:

```
private void ShowItems()
{
    var items = (from p in db.Items
                 orderby p.ID descending
                 select new { ID = p.ID, Item = p.itemName, 
                     Qty = p.quantity }).Take(5);

    GridView.DataSource = items;
    GridView.DataBind();
}
```

So my idea was to change the Take() to something like Take(*from, to*), but it isn't supported. What do I do to solve my problem?

Thanx for listening!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do it:

```
.Skip((pageNo - 1) * resultsPerPage)
.Take(resultsPerPage)
```

Comment: Should be pageNo -1, fixed it.

Comment: I noticed - I just added the comment to say "Assuming page 0" - I'll take it back out ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Skip` and `Take` methods to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Take<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, int start, int end)
{
    if (start > end) 
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid parameters");
    return collection.Skip(start).Take(end - start);
}
```